# Springboot & maven - Changing datasource configuration with maven command

Tags: java, spring, maven, testing, datasource

In my project (springboot, maven), I have tests annotated with `@TestPropertySource({"classpath:flyway.properties", "/queries/test.properties"})` to override some properties related to my datasource.
I run the test with `mvn clean test` command.

Now I would like to add a new stage to my Jenkins pipeline to perform my tests on two different data sources.

Is there a way to overwrite the values in my file (test.properties) when I run the maven command? Or could I use two different files with spring profiles or something like :

`@TestPropertySource({"classpath:flyway.properties", "/queries/test-${env/profile}.properties"})`

Any insight would be gratefully appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could have different profiles and activate the right one on demand by running:

`mvn -DargLine="-Dspring.profiles.active=myProfile" clean test`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how do the profiles help me to manage my 2 files (e.g _test-db1.properties_ & _test-db2.properties_) ? 
I'm looking for a way to change the file in the @TestPropertySource annotation, based on a value I would pass as an argument of the maven command.